# How to change proxy IP of selenium webdriver dynamically？

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, web-crawler

I‘m using **Python** & **selenium** writing a crawler program, `once Chrome webdriver instance was created, is there a way to change the proxy IP dynamically?` hope for your help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Worth looking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884089/dynamically-changing-proxy-in-firefox-with-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically change proxies in chrome driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54911913/how-to-dynamically-change-proxies-in-chrome-driver)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can change proxy without first destroying and creating a new browser instance. In my program where I implemented proxies I had a for loop create a new browser and then passed that browser as an argument to the functions I had created that needed it. Perhaps I am just ignorant of a way to dynamically do it, but as I recall the proxy information needs to be specified when the browser instance is created so again I would not think that what you are trying to do is possible...

Comment: It is possible using a remote-controlled extension or seleniumwire now [resource](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles#set-proxies-dynamically-or-with-options)