# Keep python selenium webdriver in background/ unfocused

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am downloading files with selenium and whenever a new file is downloaded, the window comes into focus. Is there a way to keep the window unfocused and maybe also not to flash orange in windows?

Currently I am on chrome but ideally it should work for firefox as well.

Comment: The `window` you mean is the download complete dialog? If that so, you can [change the browser's setting in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884089/dynamically-changing-proxy-in-firefox-with-selenium-webdriver/48816511#48816511)

Comment: You can easily set it to headless mode. reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programmatically-in-selenium-with-python

Comment: don't want it to be headless just unfocused

Answer (score 0):

If you are you talking about the Browser getting focus on the desktop, you could use selenium in docker from https://hub.docker.com/u/selenium

If you want to see what happens use the *debug version you can use VNC to look at it.

e.g. `docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -p 5900:5900 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome-debug`

then use VNC to connect to localhost:5900 with `secret` as password