# Changing proxy port with selenium while runing in c#

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, proxy, webdriver

I want to change the proxy port of my firefox driver while it is runing.
It is not important If i use the proxy settings from firefox itself or a 3rd party plugin like Omega switchy.

the main problem is

- I can NOT open and close the browser with new arguments
- firefox webdirver can not interact with about:preferences or about:config. otherwise I could change it by navigating to those pages
- I if I set a system proxy and set firefox to use the system proxy and change the systemproxy by my application every program starts to use it

A similar question has been asked here but not for c#

[Dynamically changing proxy in Firefox with Selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884089/dynamically-changing-proxy-in-firefox-with-selenium-webdriver)

Is there any way to resolve this problem?
thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What does it mean you can no open an close the browser with new arguments?

Comment: Look at following code : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.proxy?view=net-5.0

Comment: It is possible to close the selenium webdriver and open a new one and use the proxy as starting argument for firefox. that's not an option since i want to continue to use the same driver